# Needing to print the year and yearly total, print the status code and totals by for each status code

Tags: mysql

My subquery total is printing for my year total. I've tried several examples suggested by others and I get close but not what I need. The year and status codes are examples not fixed.

Year    Status
2013    A
2013    A
2013    I
2014    A
2015    I
2015    A
2016    A
2016    I

Needing to print the year and yearly total, print the status code and totals by for each status code
2013 - 3
    A - 2
    I - 1
2014 - 1
    A - 1
2015 - 2
    A - 1
    I - 1

Comment: Can you provide the database structure and the select? You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: CREATE TABLE `cvs_status_table` (
  `csv_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `csv_status` char(1) NOT NULL
) 

SELECT SUBSTR(csv_date,1,4) AS dates, csv_status, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM cvs_status_table
GROUP BY dates, csv_status

Comment: Try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7de99/8

Comment: Perfect - solved the problem. Thanks for the help.